# How can I prevent Quickbooks from changing the "DatabaseName" parameter inside the database .DSN file?

Tags: sql, sybase, quickbooks, sqlanywhere, dsn

This ".DSN" file is re-created by Quickbooks every time no user is connected. I'm trying to configure an ODBC connection using "SQL Anywhere" driver, one of the mandatory parameters needed for the configuration is the "DatabaseName". The connection works until this file is re-created, the only parameter that changes   is the "DatabaseName". Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to override the connection string using the `SQLCONNECT` environment variable.

If you set `SQLCONNECT` to `DatabaseName=YouDBName` this will override the DSN.